# How to Document doPost() Methods?

Tags: java, documentation, doxygen

I have a doPost() method which can perform one of two actions:

1. Log into an account if a "login" button is pressed.
2. Register for an account if a "register" button is pressed.

What type of documentation-block is standard to document this type of interaction?

See the following example:

```
/**
 * The account class as an example.
 */
@WebServlet("/account")
public class Account extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * What's the standard way to document
     * that registerButton and loginButton do different actions here?
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (request.getParameter("registerButton") != null) {
            // register stuff...
        }

        if (request.getParameter("loginButton") != null) {
            // login stuff...
        }
    }

    /**
     * An example of a documentation-block.
     * @param arg an integer example argument.
     * @return A boolean value as an example.
     */
    private boolean example(int arg) {
    }
```

Comment: Why not to have a `LoginServlet` and `RegistrationServlet` instead, mapped to `/login` and `/register`? Alternatively you can use a framework which is easier to code logic than plain servlets e.g. Spring Web.

Comment: When looking just at the documentation side I would use the `@param` and mention the possibilities here in a list, analogous for the response (or in case of a non void method in the `@return`).